# Adding onClick function in a variable a href

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm a begginer with Javascript and I would like to know if there is a better way to write this piece of code:

```
var images = [], 
index = 0;
images[0] = "<a href = 'link' onclick='_gaq.push(['_link', this.href]);return false;'>
<img src='image.jpg'></a>";
images[1] = "<a href = 'link1' onclick='_gaq.push(['_link', this.href]);return false;'>
<img src='image1.jpg'></a>";
index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
document.write(images[index]);
```

This code doens´t work, I think is because I'm including the onClick function inside the variable description...

The function would be to print randomically the images, but adding the _gaq.push parameters in the url image link.

Is there any other way the write this code?

Thanks

Comment: You can add event handlers without using inline versions. You can select the images in code and assign the onclick properties or add handlers for the click events to allow other handlers to be attached as well if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

No need to create the html in javascript.  You can do the following:

JavaScript (must be instantiated before the html is rendered):

```
var pushMe = function(link){
    _gaq.push(['_link', link.href]);return false;
};
```

Html:

```
<a href = "link" onclick="pushMe(this);">
<img src="image.jpg"></a>
```